# Inputting Array In Multiline Text In Android

Tags: android, arrays, loops, for-loop, output

I am new to android and am trying to make an app where the user inputs an array in a text box with inputType = textMultiLine. The problem is that I want to make it so that whenever user hits enter, the app takes input of the next array element and not treat the entire text in the textbox as one element. The code is as below :

```
    EditText input = findViewById(R.id.inputtext);
    Button show = findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView output = findViewById(R.id.output);
    String [] name = new String[3];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        name[i] = input.getText().toString();
        output.setText(name[i]);
    }
```

But whenever i try to take name[1] after hitting enter the app doesnt treat the next line as name[2] but instead treats it as name[1]. For example if type the names john,steve and frank, then i should get an array that is like this :

```
name[0] = john
name[1] = steve
name[2] = frank
```

but instead whenever I typejohn,press enter,type steve, press enter and type frank the app treats it as :

```
name[0] = john
          steve
          frank
```

also if i set the output to something like this :

```
output.setText(name[i] + i)
```

instead of getting an oupt like this :

```
john 0
steve 1
frank 2
```

I get an output like this :

```
john
steve
frank2
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

======================================================================================================================================================

EDIT 1

I tried this code but didn't work:

```
String name[] = input .getText().toString().split("\\r?\\n");

for (int i = 0 ; i < name.length; i++)
{

    output.setText(name[i]);
}
```

Still get only frank when I input john,steve and frank

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put each line to different array item :

```
String [] name = input.getText().toString().split("\n");
```

`input.getText().toString()` gives you string containing whole **EditText** content with lines separated by new line - "\n". You need to split this string to get each line.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 String name[] = input .getText().toString().split("\\r?\\n");
 String disp="";
 for (int i = 0 ; i < name.length; i++)
    {
        disp += name[i] +"\n";

    }
 output.setText(disp);
```

Comment: tried it but didn't work. Edited the original question so you can see the edited code.

Comment: click on the textbox, type john, hit enter, type steve, hit enter and type frank

Comment: I did but this time it gives me error saying cannot resolve symbol lines. Do i make it a string or int or what?

Comment: @SteviG sorry it's my mistake use name insted of line..see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following example will be useful:

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
final EditText input = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        final Button show = findViewById(R.id.button);
        final TextView output = findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                final String inputString = input.getText().toString();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(inputString)) {
                    final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    final String[] inputText = inputString.split(newLine);

                    String outputText = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {
                        outputText += inputText[i];
                        if (i != inputText.length - 1) {
                            outputText += newLine;
                        }
                    }
                    output.setText(outputText);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

[You can download de APK here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/136I-l8iMs_lq3r9GVsiHx9GvZLgtQITN/view?usp=sharing) or [here the complete source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rmR8FkbSU9nAekOk-GhxkWXVzdySLbq_/view?usp=sharing)

**(another way:simple!) In the following code it is not necessary to make a split on the input text.**

```
    final EditText input = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    final Button show = findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView output = findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            final String inputString = input.getText().toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(inputString)) {
                output.setText(inputString);
            }
        }
    });
```

***Note that, your code is wrong, because in for each loop, you override the text was setted in the previous loop.***